# Python basic - os library issue - os.path.isfile() not working as expected

Tags: python

I tried to make a small python program that lists the files and folders in a directory,
then adds the files into a file list and the directories into directory list. What I wrote:

```
import os

list_files = []
list_dir = []

enter_dir = input('Enter dir to list its content: ')

for items in os.listdir(enter_dir):
    if os.path.isfile(items):
        list_files.append(items)
    elif os.path.isdir(items):
        list_dir.append(items)
print(f'{enter_dir} has the following files: {list_files}')
print(f'{enter_dir} has the following directories: {list_dir}')
```

it is not working and the lists are empty when I print them,
funny thing when you don't enter a directory and leave it like
"for items in os.listdir():"

- it works but it works from the directory where you start the program.
  The path to the directory that I enter is correct because I did a print(items) before the for loop, and the files and folders are listed.
  When I tried debugging it seems that the if statement always returns False - don't know why.
  In Linux environment it worked for some directories that I tried, but not for all.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, each item is just an `item`, not an `items`; it's typical (and makes understanding your code easier to readers) to use plural names only for variables that store lists, not for a variable that only stores one item from a list at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns the names of files and directories, not the full path.
You need to create the full path your self using `os.path.join`:

```
import os

list_files = []
list_dir = []

enter_dir = input('Enter dir to list its content: ')

for item in os.listdir(enter_dir):
    fullItemPath = os.path.join(enter_dir, item)
    if os.path.isfile(fullItemPath):
        list_files.append(fullItemPath)
    elif os.path.isdir(fullItemPath):
        list_dir.append(fullItemPath)
print(f'{enter_dir} has the following files: {list_files}')
print(f'{enter_dir} has the following directories: {list_dir}')
```

Output (on Mac):

```
python /tmp/y.py
Enter dir to list its content: /Users
/Users has the following files: ['/Users/.localized']
/Users has the following directories: ['/Users/xxx', '/Users/Shared']
```